# In swift, what if I mark a property as final

Tags: swift, properties, final

I know if a function is marked as final, then it can't be overridden in subclass. But what if a property in a class is marked as final? I gave it a try and found it can be assigned a new value in subclass.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Final` on a property means that a subclass cannot modify the assignment logic of the property. It does not mean that the property value is immutable.

Without `final`, something like this would be allowed:

```
class X {
    var x: Int
}

class Y: X {
    override var x: Int {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I add getter and setter method to a stored property, will it become a computed property? Does it mean that it is meaningless to mark a stored property as final?

Comment: Swift abstracts away the difference between stored properties and computed properties. From outside a class, there is no way to tell if a property is a stored property or a computed property, and both can override the other in a child class. As for `final` being "meaningless", it is as meaningful on properties as it is on methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an addition to zneaks right answer, in Swift you can declare a property with let instead of var... So if you say

```
let myConstantProperty: String = "Peter"
```

No one will be able to change it... But thats just if you need a functionality like this...